# Why `\textcolor` inside math environment unexpectedly changes surrounding text (which is not inside `\textcolor`) to black?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, amsmath

### Before:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[fill=black,text=white]
            {%
                $%
                    \begin{gathered}
a+b=\text{cvar}\\ % THIS LINE WILL BE CHANGED LATER TO INCLUDE \textcolor
a=\text{cvar}-b   % THIS LINE WILL BE CHANGED LATER TO INCLUDE \textcolor
                    \end{gathered}
                $
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### After:

```
a+b=\textcolor{red}{\text{cvar}}\\
a=\textcolor{red}{\text{cvar}}-b
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately it's a general feature of tikz colour that it doesn't use the driver supported colour stack commands so does not mix well with latex colour.  In particular here latex restores the last set colour on the colour stack, but that is black, it does not know of the white colour set directly by tikz

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, can something be done to make it look as expected without dropping tikzpicture?

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}\color{white}` works in your mwe. I don't know in general.

Comment: @jfbu yes that's the best workaround currently (or within a specific node, but setting the colour using the colour stack rather than the tikz attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess this is basically what David refers to in his latest comment: instead of `text=white`, use `font=\color{white}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[fill=black,font=\color{white}]
            {%
                $%
                    \begin{gathered}
a+b=\textcolor{red}{\text{cvar}}\\
a=\textcolor{red}{\text{cvar}}-b
                    \end{gathered}
                $
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need `tikz` for this, unless you really need the `standalone` class: `empheq` (which loads `mathtools`) makes it easy to obtain the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{empheq}%
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\myblackbox}[1]{\colorbox{black}{\enspace#1\enspace}}

\newenvironment{myempheq}[2][]{%
\setkeys{EmphEqEnv}{#2}%
\setkeys{EmphEqOpt}{box=\myblackbox,#1}%
\fboxsep=8pt\color{white}\EmphEqMainEnv}%
{\endEmphEqMainEnv}

\begin{document}%

\begin{myempheq}{gather}
  a+b=\text{\color{red}cvar}\\ % THIS LINE WILL BE CHANGED LATER TO INCLUDE \textcolor
  a=\text{\color{red}cvar}-b % THIS LINE WILL BE CHANGED LATER TO INCLUDE \textcolor
\end{myempheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]