# \textcolor{}{} behaves differently within an \href in a \node

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, color, nodes

### Note:

This question is similar to [\textcolor{}{} behaves differently within a \node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447575/4301). The difference here is that

- The problem occurs inside an `\href` (within a `\node`) *and*
- The workaround *hack* solution I posted there does not work here?

Thus, I suspect that the problem is related but not identical.  Would be nice to have a *single* solution that works for both cases.

---

I would expect that using the `\MyText` (containing an `\href`) macro defined as

```
\newcommand*{\MyText}{%
    before \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{\textcolor{red}{{TeX.SE}}} after%
}
```

should *always* yield the same color for the text "before" and "after". But it appears that when I use it within a `\node` (third line), it results in different colors:

[image]

It seems as if the `\textcolor{red}{TeX.SE}` restores the color to `black` at the end if it is used within a `\node`.

Question: How do I get `\textcolor{}{}` within a `\node` to yield the same results as it does outside of a `\node`.

### Notes:

- Using `\textcolor{}{}` outside of the `\href` *does* allow the *hack* solution to work, *but*, then this won't override `colorlinks=true` (in case it is used)

### Listfiles

```
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
hyperref.sty    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  TeX-SE.out
  TeX-SE.out
 ***********
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xspace}
%%
%% The "colorlinks" here to show that moving the `\textcolor{}{}` to 
%% be outside of the \href is not a viable solution.
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%% Hack solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448043/4301
%% does not seem to work here?
\makeatletter
\let\OldTextcolor\textcolor
\newcommand*{\MyTextColor}[2]{%
    \colorlet{@SavedColor}{.}%
    \OldTextcolor{#1}{#2}%
    \color{@SavedColor}%
    \xspace%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\let\textcolor\MyTextColor}%


\newcommand*{\MyText}{%
    before \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{\textcolor{red}{{TeX.SE}}} after%
}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}

\noindent
Outside of \verb|\node|: \MyText

\begingroup
\noindent
Outside of \verb|\node|: \color{green}\MyText
\endgroup

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node [text=green, draw=blue, fill=yellow!20, inner sep=2pt] at (0,0) {Inside node: \MyText};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an ugly workaround that works both here and in the [partner question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447575/4301): set the text color first just with `green`, say, and then set the other colors *afterwards* with `draw=blue`, `fill=yellow`, say. I am aware that this is not a real solution, just a workaround, but this seems to work. Moreover, the business is rather delicate, i.e. a real solution may break other codes that worked fine so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xspace}
%%
%% The "colorlinks" here to show that moving the `\textcolor{}{}` to 
%% be outside of the \href is not a viable solution.
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%% Hack solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448043/4301
%% does not seem to work here?
\makeatletter
\let\OldTextcolor\textcolor
\newcommand*{\MyTextColor}[2]{%
    \colorlet{@SavedColor}{.}%
    \OldTextcolor{#1}{#2}%
    \color{@SavedColor}%
    \xspace%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\let\textcolor\MyTextColor}%


\newcommand*{\MyText}{%
    before \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com}{\textcolor{red}{{TeX.SE}}} after%
}%

\listfiles
\begin{document}

\noindent
Outside of \verb|\node|: \MyText

\begingroup
\noindent
Outside of \verb|\node|: \color{green}\MyText
\endgroup

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node [text=green, draw=blue, fill=yellow!20, inner sep=2pt] at (0,0) {Inside node: \MyText};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node [green, draw=blue, fill=yellow!20, inner sep=2pt] at (0,0) {Inside node: \MyText};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, with all the issues I have had with this I am leaning towards going down this path and dealing separately with any issues regarding the order of the `\tikz` options.

Comment: @PeterGrill I fully agree it is ugly. And I am not suggesting that you go that path or even accept that answer, it is just meant for others that may have the same problem and need a quick workaround. (You could of course define a tikz style that does the ordering for you.)

Comment: Agreed. `\tikstyle` is the way to go, but since my styles are often built up over layers, I need to be careful about the order. I suspect it will work just fine with perhaps a few issues that can be tweaked.

Comment: Oppsss. I meant `\tikzset`... Thanks for correcting that.